# Как конвертировать pdf в doc и odt

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

Я нашел много алгоритмов по конвертации `doc` в `pdf`,но не нашел обратного алгоритма.
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать это на `windows` и на `linux`.
Pdf я делаю с помощью библиотеки `LimeReport`.Там нет методов для конвертации в `doc`/`odt`.

Comment: Если вы генерируете отчёт в pdf, то... можно найти либы для создания doc и odt, и генерировать их непросредственно с "оригинала", а не с pdf.

Comment: В общем случае почти никак. PDF — это формат print-ready, а не для редактирования. А так смотрите в сторону приобретения Adobe Acrobat (не Reader!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, что PDF может и не содержать слоя с текстом того, что вы там видите. А значит, ваша конвертация превращается в задачу распознавания образов - OCR-программы вам в помощь.

Если же вам повезло и слой с текстом есть, можно использовать [Abiword](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37548/pdf-to-word-conversion-software)

```
abiword --to=doc example.pdf
```

Или LibreOffice

```
libreoffice --invisible --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML"
```

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть в windows?

Comment: Также, только версии пакетов нужны под венду.

Comment: Добавлю ещё, что pdf создавался как формат хранения и представления, а не редактирования. Поэтому "лучше не надо".